# JQuery autocomplete isn't autocompleting/providing suggestions

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have followed the example on this website:

http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/example-get-autocomplete-feature-in-javajsp-with-jquery-api/

Instead of the jquery files used in the example I used

jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

jquery-1-10.2.js

Instead of "countries" table I used "footballplayers" table in MySQL which I created myself. I am sure that there is a fully functioning connection between MySQL table and eclipse.

The footballplayers table has 4 columns:

id
FootballerName
FootballerPosition
FootballerTeam

I want to search by FootballerName.

The problem I am having is a drop-down box should appear and provide suggestions but I do not get any. What could the possible problems be?

Also, I am using Glassfish Server.

Sections I have changed: 
list.jsp:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con  =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project","root","root");
 Statement st=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM footballplayers");
```

index.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi! Are you getting any console error? Could you provide some code?

Comment: No console errors unfortunately. Runs on the server smoothly just doesn't return any suggestions.